# socket io NOT FOUND ERROR?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to learn socket.io and Nodejs for the first time.

I have installed the nodejs and socket.io on my server in the `root`. everything is installed in the root.

on my domain, i created a `test-folder` and created an `index.html` file in that folder and placed this code inside it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.2/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var iosocket = io.connect();
            iosocket.on('connect', function () {
                $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li>Connected</li>'));
                iosocket.on('message', function(message) {
                    $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text(message));
                });
                iosocket.on('disconnect', function() {
                    $('#incomingChatMessages').append('<li>Disconnected</li>');
                });
            });
            $('#outgoingChatMessage').keypress(function(event) {
                if(event.which == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    iosocket.send($('#outgoingChatMessage').val());
                    $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text($('#outgoingChatMessage').val()));
                    $('#outgoingChatMessage').val('');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
Incoming Chat: <ul id="incomingChatMessages"></ul>
<br />
<input type="text" id="outgoingChatMessage">
</body>
</html>
```

I then went back to the root and created an `app.js` file and placed this code in it:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , http = require('http')
    , socketio = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/var/www/vhosts/my-website.net/httpdocs/test-folder/index.html'));
}).listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');
});
socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    });
});
```

And ran this command from the SSH:

```
node app.js
```

The command above retunr this:

```
Listening at: http://localhost:8080
```

I then opened the index.html file from the browser like so:

```
http://my-website.net/test-folder/index.html
```

but when i looked inside the console, i see the following error repeating over and over:

```
socket.io.min.js:1 GET http://my-website.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1505580173244-3 404 (Not Found)
```

I have no idea what that means or what i need to do. could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is inside your head tag.If you've installed socket.io there is no need to take it by link
**let's replce this:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.2/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

**with this one:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: (index):7 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

Comment: @DavidHope Is `/socket.io/socket.io.js` loading correctly?

Comment: @Boaz, i'm so confused with this socket.io... I don't have any /socket.io/socket.io.js... where is the socket.io.js should be on my server?

Comment: when you install it on your server, for example in your root.. the files will be created.but I've got a suggestion for you. to learn it well, you can see this tutorial which doesn't take your time. it's easy and make u understand well. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_environment.htm

Comment: @Mehdi, yes thanks.. that is what i'm trying to do.. trying to learn it and this is the first time ever attempting anything with socket.io